# Why do we tie 7, 8, 11, 13 on tzitzit

Tags: tzitzis, tying-knots-kosheir

When tying tzitzit, you tie 7, 8, 11, then 13 krichot. I know the reason for 7 and 13 is because there are 7 shamayim in the rakiah and six passage ways between them, so there is 7 for the minimum, and 6+7 or 13 for the maximum. But what is the reason for the 8 and 11?

Comment: The 7-13 are supposed to remind us of "not less than 7, not more than 13 [Menachos 39a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.39a?lang=bi) when everyone wore Techeiles (whether 7-13 means winds or Chulyos - sets of winds - is a Machlokes Rishonim where Raavad/Natronai Gaon say winds and everyone else says Chulyos). The 39 has a numerical significance of YKVK Echad. The 8 and 11 therefore help aid that. 7 and then 8 become 15, which is YK. 11 itself is VK (6+5), and 13 is Echad. What I'd like to know is "when" 7-8-11-13 was adopted, 10-5-6-5 is used by Moroccan Sephardim, and Yemenites do 7 Chulyos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

The 7 and 8 equal 15, like yud and hey, the first two letters of Hashem's Name. The 11 can be split into 5 and 6, like vav and hey, the last two letters of Hashem's Name. The 13 can be split into 1, 8, and 4 like alef, chet, and dalet, so it's echad. So the tzitzit mean Hashem Echad, G-d is one, and also the 13 could be for the 13 Attributes of Mercy.

See [this](https://ohr.edu/3003) responsa from [Ohr Somayach](https://www.ohr.edu/).

Also note that Sephardim do not tie this way. They tie 5, 6, 10, 5 like yud-kay-vav-kay.